# Chromecast Google Cast SDK custom receiver is not getting detected

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, widevine, custom-receiver

I am just starting implementing chrome cast , I started working on custom receiver app and i copy pasted code from google documentation and hosted on free web hosting : https://thirsty-roentgen-206e45.netlify.com, I registered my chrome-cast device (NVIDIA Shield TV) under developers console. I launched google sample cast app on Lenovo tab (Android) I don't see my cast app in the cast apps dialog of sender app. what Am i missing here? I am new to Android and also Java script, Can you help me understand please?

My first question is My NVIDIA Shield TV has already one receiver app running i think so because I can cast videos from sample app and also youtube from my ios mobile, can I run two receiver apps running ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to reboot your shield

the receiver it is web page, and you use a browser to navigate between multiple receiver

Comment: How do I access the existing receiver app from the webpage ? Can you help me understand please , and also I do not have any app running in the device , it will load it from the link I updated in the developer console , do I need to have any app running on the receiver device ?

Comment: you don't need to run any app on the receiver.
in your sender, when you set your cast, you give him the id of the receiver (the id you find in console dev) them your shield/chrome cast, make a request to find the real url.

google has own app do to that

Comment: I used https:/cast-tse-demo.firebaseapp.com/sender/?appid=<yourAppId> link to see but I don't see my receiver app running in the debugger